# To find the Expectation of exponential of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What is the expectation

$$\mathbb E[\exp(W_t)],$$
$$\mathbb E[\exp(W_t^4)]$$

where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian and $W_t∼N(0,t)$? I know that the standard Brownian motion has mean of 0 and variance having the value of $t$. Also, I understand that the first one is some form of geometric brownian motion. How do I proceed from here on? I can try and do the second one myself, if somehow the first one is explained by someone

Comment: You should the fact that $B_t\sim N(0,t)$.  Then the problem reduces to find the $4$-th moment and the moment generating function of a Gaussian r.v.

Comment: Is $B_t$ a mistype for $W_t$?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: ShiS, in the very first version of your question you asked for the expectation $E(W_t^4)$ but now it seems you are asking for the expectation of the exponential of $W_t^4$,  is that the case?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typographical error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W_t \sim N(0,t)$. So $Ee^{W_t}=\frac  1 {\sqrt {2\pi} t} \int_{\mathbb R} e^{x} e^{-\frac {x^{2}} {2t}}dx$. Now $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{x} e^{-\frac {x^{2}} {2t}}dx=e^{t/2}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\frac {(x-t)^{2}} {2t}}dx=\sqrt {2\pi} t e^{t/2}$.

You can also use the general formula for the genearting function of normal distribution  (*) which immediately gives $Ee^{W_t}=e^{t/2}$

(*): ( $Ee^{cX}=e^{c\mu} e^{c^{2}\sigma^{2}/2}$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma^{2}$ is the variance of $X$).

Also $Ee^{W_t^{4}} =\infty$.